# Variable within function accessible to outside world

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to have access to $lastID when calling `raw` Is there a way to do this?

```
public static $lastID;  
public function raw($sql){

    if(!$result = mysql_query($sql)){
        throw new Exception("Could not perform query: " .mysql_error());
    }

    self::$lastID = mysql_insert_id();
    return($result);

}
```

Edit: it is a class member, it is static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context isn't clear as but it looks as though $lastID is a class memeber, in which case to access it from within methods of that class you should use:

```
$this->lastID;
```

The other issue I can see in your code is that this line will not work

```
self::$lastID = mysql_insert_id();
```

As `$lastID` isn't static. Either declare `$lastID` as static (in which case its state will be shared across all objects of the class)

```
//change this
var $lastID; 

//to this to declare $lastID as static
static $lastID;
```

Or use `$this->` rather than `self::`

```
$this->lastID = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Okay, I declared it as static, but I'm still confused as how I can access it outside the class.

Comment: NM, figured it out:

CLASSNAME::$lastID;

Answer (score 1):

you have to use inside raw

```
global $lastId;
```

Here's the related documentation http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You can't declare variables using `var` when it is anything other than a class member. You also can't declare a function as public unless it is a method.